# Multithread loop which comparing two Strings

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, if-statement

I have exercise to learn multithread. I have one correct password like: xxYYmmDD
xx is a initials from my "Employees" list, YY is a year of birth, mm is a month of birth and DD is a day of birth. For example: Nichole Hunter 09/10/93 password is: NH930910.
But this loop know only about it a password start from initials and after that have 6 numbers. (later i have to create other loops with another method and compare which method with multithread is faster to find password but this is not important now)

I have loop which work in multithreads and for every single initial adding a String of number from 000000 to 999999 and checking it equals to correct password.
I have no idea why instruction from "if" is never call. Some one know how to help?
And how to stop other Threads if i find correct password?

```
executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
        String finalCorrect = correct;

        for(String x : inicials){
            executorService.submit(()->{
            for(int count=0;count<999999; count++){
                
                if(finalCorrect.equals(x+String.format("%06d", count).trim())){
                    System.out.println("Correct password is: "+x+String.format("%06d", count).trim());
                    System.out.println("The really password is: "+ finalCorrect);
                    break;
                }
            }
                    }
            );

        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

Comment: whats in `initials`? Can you check that `finalCorrect.startsWith(x)` returns true?

Comment: initials is a list of the initials of all employees.
finalCorrect.startsWith(x) return false throught all the loop

Comment: that's the error then, if the two initial chars of `finalCorrect` are not in the list `initials` you cannot found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is essentially correct. The problem seems to be in the initialization parameters. If, as for your example, the correct password (`finalCorrect`), starts with `NH` then inside list `initials` there must be the value `NH`.

As for stopping the working threads once the solution is found, you can call `executorService.shutdownNow()` to attempt to stop the threads. Inside the loop you will have to check for the interrupted status.

Here is an adaptation of your code with a bit more logging, that stops the working threads:

```
    ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

    for(String x : inicials){
        System.out.println("Checking " + x);
        executorService.submit(()->{
                    for(int count=0;count<999999; count++){

                        if(finalCorrect.equals(x+String.format("%06d", count).trim())){
                            System.out.println("Correct password is: "+x+String.format("%06d", count).trim());
                            System.out.println("The really password is: "+ finalCorrect);
                            // Attempt to stop all the threads...
                            executorService.shutdownNow();
                            break;
                        }

                        // Test if the thread has been requested to stop
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            System.out.println("Interrupted " + x);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("End " + x);
                }
        );

    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Using the new Streams features of Java 8, you could implement the same aPproach with a more compact form:

```
    inicials.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 999999).mapToObj(i -> x + String.format("%06d", i)))
            .filter(finalCorrect::equals)
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(x -> System.out.println("Found correct password: " + x));
```

Comment: Thats thread kiler work very well.
The loop where i checked the password didnt work because my auto Employee Generator (where i download a data from some fake name generator website and creating new Employee object) but when i create some Employe object by myself and add to list that work fine.
I have no idea why Employe generator broke my if statment...